# CRC Calculation of a string of bytes

Tags: arrays, crc

I need to calculate a CRC based in difference byte value of the data. I have an example but I am not able to get results. I have been looking for CRC online calculators but I don't know how it works. The example that I have is this:

0xA5 0x5A 0x00 0x0A 0x43 0x01 0x25 **CRC** 0x0d 0x0a

**CRC** = 0x00 ^ 0x0A ^ 0x43 ^ 0x01 ^ 0x25 = 0x6D

Thank in advance

Comment: That's just XORing the bytes together (`^` means XOR). CRC calculators you'll find online will use more complex algorithms.

Comment: @Rup - It's possible that it is is a CRC, with polynomial 0xD5.

Comment: Once I know XORing I found an online calculator in this website https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/ where CheckSum8 Xor return the correct value

Comment: @AngelGonzález - true, but CRC8 using polynomial 0xD5 also returns the correct value. I noted this in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

With only one sample, I can't be sure, but using the online calculator link below, with CRC8_DVB_S2, polynomial 0xD5, the calculated CRC is 0x6D.

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html